# how do i get request value use AXIOS on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, axios

now im doing laravel project. i'm implementing AXIOS code for complete my javascript code. do i able to get all the input element using axios code?

here is what i've been doing right now

```
{{ Form::open(['id' => 'reportData', 'url' => 'reports', 'method' => 'POST', 'name' => 'formreport']) }}

<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="lastname">

{{ Form::close() }}
```

here is my axio code

```
$('#getdata').on('click', function(e) {
        var formreport = new FormData(); 
        axios.post('/report/draft', formreport)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
    });
```

but the isnot work. the result that i want is. i want to get

`$request->firstname` and `$request->lastname` value from the controllers use AXIOS code..

do i able to do that? please advice